# Why do i get low quality audio input in raspberry pi 3 using Bluetooth headset?

Tags: audio, bluetooth, speech-recognition, raspberry-pi3, pulseaudio

Im working on project that implements speech recognition on @Raspberry_Pi

I use Bluetooth microphone for audio input and use pulseaudio as driver, but i get low quality sound that make me can't continue further step. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: You may get a more specialized answer on the [raspberrypi.se] Stack Exchange site, but please keep in mind [what topics you can post about there](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: does your project run on a laptop OK with good audio ? just to isolate whether issue is hardware or software

Comment: What do you mean by "low quality" ? HFP/SCL only supports a maxium of 16 kHz sampling rate.